# RegisterGenericDecorator ignores condition

Tags: decorator, autofac, cqrs

Conditions:

- Autofac: 4.9.1
- .NET Framework: 4.7.2

I have a generic command handler:

```
public interface ICommand<TResult> : IValidatableObject
{
}

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
                 where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>, IValidatableObject
{
    TResult Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

I have a decorator that I want to use for multiple, but not all, implementations of the ICommandHandler (I am going to use a custom attribute to differentiate handlers):

```
public sealed class LoggingDecorator<TCommand, TResult> : ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> 
                              where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>, IValidatableObject
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> _handler;

    public LoggingDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public TResult Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        var test = 0;

        return _handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

I am trying to register them with AutoFac as follows:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
               .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
            decoratorType: typeof(LoggingDecorator<,>),
            serviceType: typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
            condition: _decoratorContext =>
            {
                return false; // true;
            });
```

Seems like the condition is ignored, the decorator is "assigned" to all handlers always.
Have I mis-configured the registration in AutoFac? Or did I miss something else?

How to achieve that the decorator is not registered if the condition returns 'false' in RegisterGenericDecorator method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofac 4.9.1 is a pretty old version now (3+ yrs). I know that some behaviour around decorator conditions was fixed in v6.0.0; see [this issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1209) where upgrading fixed someone's problem that sounds similar to yours.

I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version; if upgrading doesn't fix it, put together a minimal repro and raise an issue on our github repo.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will try to update Autofac, unfortunately, Autofac it is not backward compatible and generates many errors after the upgrade. For instance connected with "ResolveComponent" method and different parameters there. I will try :)

Comment: upgrading Autofac to version 6.3.0 solved the problem. Although it wasn't a quick fix because of breaking changes in new versions of Autofac